# Showing java.lang.String issue when declaring String in java

Tags: java, string

[image]

I am not getting why it showing error
I am beginner in java , thank you

Comment: Don't name your OWN class `String` it overides the builtin one

Comment: @tomerpacific `String` is not a reserved word in Java, otherwise the OP would never have been able to call their own class `String`. What this code does is replace (hide) the default `String` (`java.lang.String`) with OPs own `String` (`FirstJava.String`) in the package `FirstJava`. That means the OP either needs to rename their class, or fully qualify the class name (i.e. `java.lang.String s1 = "Anik"`).

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Just so you know, best practice is to include the text of your code and error messages in the body of your question, rather than as an image.  (Check out the discussion behind this advice in this post on meta: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)).

Answer (score 3):

#### Problem

As your named your own class `String`, it hides the built-in class `java.lang.String`

```
String s = "Anik";
^^^^^^     ^^^^^^
|          | built-in java.lang.String
|
your class FirstJava.String
```

---

#### Solution

**Never** name a class, a variable, whatever like an existing stuff, of your own or built-in

Answer (score 1):

The String is not a reserved keyword it's a predefined non-primitive datatype in java that comes under package java.lang.String(class) that is by default imported in a java program. Also you should not use names/identifiers that have already being used as we see in case of String.

```
public class String {
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
  java.lang.String string = "Anik";
  System.out.println(string);
  }
}
```